# How can i put selected images from photos app on macbook to the camera roll on iPhone 5?

Tags: iphone, ios, itunes, photos

So i import images from my dslr to the photos app on my macbook which works perfectly but I only want to put a few of them onto my phone so it appears in my camera roll. I am aware of syncing an album through Itunes however they do not appear in the camera roll.

Is there a simple method to transfer select images from photos to the camera roll?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as both devices are in the same WiFi network and have Bluetooth enabled you can use AirDrop to send pictures between devices:

- select the photos to share
- tap/click on the sharing icon (and select AirDrop)
- wait for the target device to appear
- send it over

Answer (score 0):

Get an app called “Transfer”[image]

Put it onto all your hardware, ie: phone, computer, iPad ect.
Open on both devices and select one to send and one to receive. They will sinc themselves. The receiving appliance you need to give approval.
Open photos and select photos you want to send. Press send.

Comment: Adding an App Store link for the app you recommend will make it easier for others to find it.